# Why str.scan not working when running file?

Tags: ruby

When I try to run my file

`$ ruby file.rb`

I get

```
file.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `str' for main:Object (NameError)
```

The file doesn't seem to recognize `str.scan`. My line is

```
@file_split = str.scan(/ \+\d{11} /)
```

I'm missing something that I should require?

Fixed: I was missing the variable name!

Comment: What's `str`? You're missing a variable.

Comment: Can you show where you're defining str.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str` variable should be initialized in the `file.rb`. For example like that:

```
str = ' +45754646467 '
```

and then do you thing

```
@file_split = str.scan(/ \+\d{11} /)
```